# reactjs object doesn't have key __reactInternalInstance

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I copied this function from another stackoverflow subject (to call child methods outside render) and it worked in a small test project

```
window.FindReact = function(dom) {
  for (var key in dom) {
    if (key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance$")) {
        var compInternals = dom[key]._currentElement;
        var compWrapper = compInternals._owner;
        var comp = compWrapper._instance;
        return comp;
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

I made a class that shows a messagebox in mid of screen (Fade-in; show msg few seconds; then fade out)

and I could call the method to show the message of the child component directly thanks to above function.
So all good.

Then I copied that object (messagebox) to my main project and copied above function to the parent object.
And when I call it, no key ... well not the key I'm looking for

i listed the keys both of the working and failing project. all keys are the same except the first one (which is missing in the fail project)

```
key=__reactInternalInstance$bv23g7yipka
```

The fail project works, no errors, also the message component works (can call from inside to show message)

I really have no idea why this fails (key is missing), hope some of you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked the package.js and noticed the different versions of all modules.
So updated them (react/react-dom/webpack/babel-loader)
and then it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using using React 17, you can try "__reactFiber" instead of "__reactInternalInstance". It seems React changed this property name in React 17.