# Is it possible to retrieve a component's instance from a React Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

Before v16 of React -- that is, before the introduction of React fibers -- it was possible to take a DOM element and retrieve the React component instance as follows:

```
const getReactComponent = dom => {
  let found = false;
  const keys = Object.keys(dom);

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (key.startsWith('__reactInternalInstance$')) {
      const compInternals = dom[key]._currentElement;
      const compWrapper = compInternals._owner;
      const comp = compWrapper._instance;
      found = comp;
    }
  });

  return found || null;
};
```

This no longer works for React v16, which uses the new Fiber implementation. Specifically, the above code throws an error at the line `const comparWrapper = compInternals._owner` because there is no `_owner` property anymore. Thus you cannot also access the `_instance`.

My question here is how would we retrieve the instance from a DOM element in v16's Fiber implementation?

Comment: Why not [React devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs object doesn't have key \_\_reactInternalInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829051/reactjs-object-doesnt-have-key-reactinternalinstance)

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: that isn't a duplicate as that person isn't dealing with the difference between React pre v16.

Comment: @OriDrori: Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: React devtools allow gives you the ability to inspect react elements in the chrome console.

Comment: @OriDrori: That's true, but that's not what I need to do. I need to retrieve the component object programmatically from a DOM element that contains a component.

Comment: "In some rare cases I need to inspect a React component that has been rendered into the DOM" :) Anyway - they do it grammatically, and the code of the tool might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the function below ([updated to work for React <16 and 16+](https://src-bin.com/en/q/1bf6a0e)):

```js
window.FindReact = function(dom) {
    let key = Object.keys(dom).find(key=>key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance$"));
    let internalInstance = dom[key];
    if (internalInstance == null) return null;

    if (internalInstance.return) { // react 16+
        return internalInstance._debugOwner
            ? internalInstance._debugOwner.stateNode
            : internalInstance.return.stateNode;
    } else { // react <16
        return internalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
var someElement = document.getElementById("someElement");
FindReact(someElement).setState({test1: test2});
```

Comment: It can not work when env is production

Answer (score 0):

React 17 is slightly different:

```
function findReact(dom) {
    let key = Object.keys(dom).find(key => key.startsWith("__reactFiber$"));
    let internalInstance = dom[key];
    if (internalInstance == null) return "internalInstance is null: " + key;

    if (internalInstance.return) { // react 16+
        return internalInstance._debugOwner
            ? internalInstance._debugOwner.stateNode
           : internalInstance.return.stateNode;
    } else { // react <16
        return internalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance;
   }
}
```

the domElement in this is the tr with the data-param-name of the field you are trying to change:

```
var domElement = ?.querySelectorAll('tr[data-param-name="<my field name>"]')
```