# Chrome extension - content script is not showing all available properties in dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

why I cant get the properties : `__reactInternalInstance` and `__reactEventHandlers` of input element from the content script inside chrome extension but I can get the properties from the chrome console devtools?

there is a way to get them from the scope of the chrome extension?

thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: Please read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113969/get-reactinstance-from-javascript-in-chrome-extension/50721603

Comment: Solutions: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: @wOxxOm It's actually works, thank you :)